# Android Studio 4.1.2: Type com.hoho.android.usbserial.BuildConfig is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle

so AS tells me that "Type com.hoho.android.usbserial.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:

...\usb-serial-for-android\usbSerialForAndroid\build.transforms\53759cf0d63e199b707a7ba0cbe9c081\classes\classes.dex

...\usb-serial-for-android\usbSerialExamples\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\debug\mergeExtDexDebug\classes.dex

build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
       implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.3.0'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}
```

library.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments = [                    // Raspi   Windows   LinuxVM   ...
                'rfc2217_server_host': '192.168.0.100',
                'rfc2217_server_nonstandard_baudrates': 'true',   // true    false     false
        ]
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
    implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.3.0'
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'device', 'anyDevice'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':usbSerialForAndroid')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
}
```

gradle-wraper.properties:

```
#Tue Oct 13 21:20:09 CEST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Do `com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.3.0` and `project(':usbSerialForAndroid')` not refer to the same library?

Comment: well i don't get how gradle works. In the first case it's referring to the online repository and in the second it's pointing to a local folder. So both of those references are resolving to the same file?
Then which reference do i remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you are referencing the same library twice, with

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':usbSerialForAndroid')
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.3.0
}
```

This means that Grade is finding two libraries with the **same package name** which obviously causes a clash.

So you should only be declaring your dependencies in your app: build.grade file.

---

I presume you've cloned the repository locally, if there's a particular reason for this (you've made changes) then keep the `project` implementation, otherwise just use the other one, but move it to the app:build.gradle file.